# Static Binding to Singleton Mysteriously Fails

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following singleton class which contains the following property:

```
public class Manager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsOnline
    ...

    public static Manager Instance
    ...
}
```

In the mark-up I am trying to change the color of a button based on this online property:

```
<Button.Style>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
     <Binding Source="{x:Static storage:Manager.Instance}" Path="IsOnline"/>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8000FF00"/>
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

This binding `<Binding Source="{x:Static storage:Manager.Instance}" Path="IsOnline"/>` fails with the exception:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension'.

I have quadruple-checked the "storage" namespace; I know it is both referenced and correct.  The Instance property is static, so I do not understand why this binding would fail. I have similar bindings to static properties all over that work just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it fail if you use <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static storage:Manager.Instance}, Path=IsOnline}">?

Comment: Yes it fails in that case, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a sample app that does exactly what you're describing, it works with no issues. You can download it [here](http://cid-7c2b4bc5568e1ebe.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/StaticBindingTest.zip).

Comment: I'm going to assume it's something with the control library we're using (Infragistics). In my posted code example I simplified it to a button but it is actually an Infragistics ToggleButton. I guess that isolates the problem to that, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: The easiest way to know is to get my sample code and change the Button by an Infragistics ToggleButton...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a ValueConverter to inspect the value that the StaticExtension is getting?
(See method 2 on [this page](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html))

Comment: This is a run-time exception generated on start-up as soon as the button is loaded. It never makes it to the value converter.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same weird problem!
Solution:

You **MUST** instantiate the class before doing any XAML operations with that class!